# "Downgrading" from Win 8.1 HDD to Win 7 on SSD install

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, ssd

I have a brand new Lenovo M93p with a nice 7200 HDD. I have a 500 Gb SSD in my laptop (which I plan to move into the desktop).

I want to downgrade from 8.1 to 7 on the new machine and am not at all sure how to do this as I have no COA sticker on the new machine. (I do have the official Win 8 Pro sticker.)

Do I have to upgrade first to Win 7? Can I just stick in the SSD drive and mark it as primary once I install Win 7 on it? I am not at all sure of the sequence of things and more than a little nervous (see below).

I can find parts of this in various places but grateful for any newbie pointers, having lost several DAYS trying to get Win 7 running properly after the SSD install on the laptop.

My previous nightmare was because my COA sticker was unreadable on the old machine. I ended up sticking a new Windows install on it not realizing it was only the 30 day version! I have lived with "Not Genuine" ever since. (That is the very short version of what happened.)

EDITED 6 May to clarify

Comment: Have you read this [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2832566/)? Also, the bit about the SSD is not clear. Do you want to take it out of your laptop and use it in your new desktop?

Comment: Karan - thanks that article looks spot on. And yest taking to SSD out of the laptop. Time to call Lenovo.

Answer (score -1):

You can't "Upgrade" to an *older* OS. That would be *downgrading*. Microsoft does not support downgrading, except on computers that came with Windows 8 preinstalled by the OEM. You would have to either dualboot (have both OS's installed side by side) or install Windows 7 over Windows 8.

Installing the older OS over the newer one may require you to wipe the hard drive first. It would also require purchasing a valid license for windows 7 if there is no COA. According to several places ([here](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/11e-Windows-E-and-Edge-series/No-COA-license-key-on-new-laptop/td-p/1030775) is one), there *might* be one under the battery.

Comment: He has a COA.  He is asking how to downgrade to WIndows 7.  Windows 8 machines do not place the key on a sticker, but he has a COA, the license is embedded into firmware

Comment: 100% you CAN downgrade. Ihave legit 8.1 Pro so can downgrade to 7 Pro. Does not look as easy as I hoped but would rather have two machines running 7 which I know quite well. May well upgrade to 10 in a few months but not until others have ironed out the bugs :-)